# Site Speed for Google Analytics not working

Tags: google-analytics

I am successfully tracking traffic on a site (so far over 150 hits), however the Site Speed is still showing all zeroes. I know that the default is to only calculate speed for 1% of the requests, but it seems that nothing is getting tracked at all for Site Speed. I'm using the newest version of Chrome.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site speed sample rate sets the percentage of users to be tracked not the percentage of requests. Here's what [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate) say:

> This setting determines how often site speed tracking beacons will be sent. By default, 1% of users will be automatically be tracked. Note: Analytics restricts Site Speed collection hits for a single property to the greater of 1% of users or 10K hits per day in order to ensure an equitable distribution of system resources for this feature.

In your case, if you don't expect to have more than 10K hits to your property in a single day, you can safely set the sample rate to 100%. Note: this has to be done in the create method:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the [`_setSightSpeedSampleRate()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration?csw=1#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSiteSpeedSampleRate) method? That would be my best guess. According to the Google docs:

> The `_setSiteSpeedSampleRate()` method must be called prior to `_trackPageview()` in order to be effective.

Comment: nyuen: I haven't tried that, thanks. Actually, I think the issue is that their default only tracks 1% of users, not 1% of requests. I've made all 180 hits, so that could be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for this appears to be for the older `ga.js` Google Analytics, which uses the `_gaq` array, and not the newer Universal `analytics.js`. I could be wrong though. The [answer that Philip provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24813500/456814) appears to be for the newer `analytics.js`.